# Defining and calling Auto-Implemented Properties in the same class

Tags: c#, oop

OK, I am really ashamed to ask but... having declared

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            return this.HttpContext.User != null &&
                   this.HttpContext.User.Identity != null &&
                   this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
```

why can't I just do this inside a method in the same class ?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(IsAuthenticated)
        {...do something...}
    }
```

as:

```
The name 'IsAuthenticated' does not exist in the current context
```

It does not make sense to instantiate the class  to create a reference to its 'IsAuthenticated' autoimplemented property, as the class default constructor is fired as I call the ActionResult Index method (even if it needs not being explicitly declared).

Confused...

Comment: I'm confused about what you're confused about... There is no auto-implemented property in your code. An auto-implemented property would be something like `public bool IsAutoImplemented { get; set; }`. There's nothing in the `get` or `set`; the compiler is automatically generating the code for those.

Comment: But you can have an auto-implemented property with a getter only. That is the one in my example: public bool IsAutoImplemented { get;} as I don't need to set it but to retrieve a value that's been setted elsewhere (HttpContext for instance). What's wrong in having a getter-only auto-implemented property?

Comment: are you sure the code is in the same class? it must work, no need to create an instance (unless the function from where you are calling the property is static...)

Comment: But, that's not what you have in your example. You have a fully, manually implemented, read-only property. And that should be working. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/RyYJDQ.

Comment: You're right Gusman. It should work and it works. It was just an additional parentheses  missed at the end of the code page. My bad, sorry guys and thanks for your time and consideration.